# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\usbwebserver\root \hatsker.ru\vpered.php on line 43

Tags: php

Я работаю на php 5.4.Хочу чтобы при клике на кнопку каждый раз выводились 5 элементов массива. Хранение левого и правого предела реализовано в файле. Вот код:

```
<?php
$path = realpath(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
$file = $path . '\katalog_articles_vzlom.html';
$text = file_get_contents($file);
$text1 = explode("<hr>", $text);
$count = count($text1);
$shag = 5;
$left;
$right;
$ostatok = $count % 5;

if ($count < 5)
    {
    foreach($text1 as $v) echo $v . '<hr>';
    }
  else
    {
    $file2 = fopen("bufer1.txt", "r");
    $left = (int)(fread($file2, 1));
    $right = (int)(fread($file2, 2));
    fclose($file2);

    // echo $count. gettype($count).'<br />';
    // echo $ostatok.gettype($ostatok).'<br />';
    // echo $left.gettype($left).'<br />';
    // echo $right.gettype($right).'<br />';

    if ($right > $count && $left < $count)
        {
        for ($i = $count - $ostatok; $i < $count; ++$i) echo text1[$i] . '<hr>';
        $text_p = file_get_contents('pages.html');
        print_r($text_p);
        }
      else
        {
        for ($i = $left; $i < $right; $i++) echo text1[$i] . '<hr>';
        $text_p = file_get_contents('pages.html');
        print_r($text_p);
        }

    $file3 = fopen("bufer1.txt", "w");
    $left+= $shag;
    $right+= $shag;
    if ($left > $count)
        {
        $left = 0;
        $right = 5;
        }

    fwrite($file3, $left);
    fwrite($file3, $right);
    fclose($file3);
    }

// =str_split($text);
// foreach ($text1 as $v) echo $v. '<hr>';
// for( $i=0;$i<5;++$i) echo $text1[$i].'<hr>';

/*$count=count(text1);
while($predel2<$count)
{

// for($i=$predel1;$i<$predel2;$i++) echo text1[$i].'<hr>';

}*/

// echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
// print_r($text1);

/*$file2=$path.'\pages.html';
$text2=file_get_contents($file2);*/
/*$arr=str_split($text);
foreach ($text as $v) echo $v. '<br';*/

// echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text));
// print_r($text2);

?>
```

Выводил значения тип левого и нижнего предела, они все int  не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: вы тот код привели? в этом файле на строке 43 нет `[`

Comment: да прошу прощения вот нормальный код:

Comment: for ($i = $count - $ostatok; $i < $count; ++$i) echo text1[$i] . '<hr>';

Comment: в этой строчке возникает ошибка

Comment: `text1[$i]` не замечаете отсутствия чего-либо? Включите отображение ошибок и нотисов, поиск косяков куда проще станет

Comment: @teran отсутствие `$`, всегда замечают. =)

Comment: укажите пожалуйста в какой строке(приведите её) отсутствует $, а то я  уже с ног сбился её искать